# Strategies for dealing with DateTime.Now in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, datetime

I have business logic that does not perform certain functions on Saturday or Sunday.  I want my unit tests to verify that these functions are performed, but the tests will fail on Saturday/Sunday.

I figure the easiest route is to have the unit tests convey a friendly message stating that the test results are not valid if they are run on Saturday/Sunday.

With C# / NUnit...

```
Assert.That(
  DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek !=      
  DayOfWeek.Saturday, "This test cannot be run on Saturday or Sunday");
```

Is it possible/advisable to try and mock the date?  Are there other strategies for handling this scenario?

Comment: ISystemClock in Microsoft.Extensions.Internal;

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible/advisable to try and mock the date?

Yes, not only that it is advisable but it is the only way to reliably unit test your code in isolation. Suppose that you wanted to test the following (meaningless) method:

```
public bool Foo()
{
    return (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```

It's more than obvious that you can't test it because it relies on a static method (the static [Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) property to be more precise). It's clear that components which are tightly coupled like this cannot be unit tested in isolation.

Now consider this improvement (separation of concerns with constructor DI):

```
private readonly Func<DateTime> _nowProvider;
public SomeClass(Func<DateTime> nowProvider)
{
    _nowProvider = nowProvider;
}

public bool Foo()
{
    return (_nowProvider().DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```

Now that's much better and easier to unit test. `SomeClass` no longer depends on a non-deterministic date. In the real application you would obviously instantiate `SomeClass` like this:

```
var s = new SomeClass(() => DateTime.Now);
s.Foo();
```

and in your unit test you will mock it so that you can verify both cases:

```
var subjectUnderTest = new SomeClass(() => new DateTime(2011, 1, 3));
var actual = subjectUnderTest.Foo();
// assertions, ...
```

Comment: This is a simpler approach compare to having an interface controlled with IoC. However, if all you want is to mock the current datetime I think is great.

Answer (score 7):

You should create an abstraction over the system clock, as the system clock represents a [Volatile Dependency](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-1/235). This allows you write [RTM unit tests](http://www.osherove.com/blog/2009/12/31/rtm-ready-tests.html) on code that depends on system resources and external resources.

An abstraction over the system clock is pretty simple and could look like this:

```
public interface ISystemClock
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

Classes in your application that depend on the system clock should  have an `ISystemClock` as constructor argument. For unit testing scenario's you can use an `ISystemClock` implementation that looks like this:

```
public class FakeSystemClock : ISystemClock
{
    // Note the setter.
    public DateTime Now { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use this fake clock in your unit tests like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException),
    "Service should throw an exception when called on saturday.")]
public void DoSomething_WhenCalledOnSaturday_ThrowsException()
{
    // Arrange
    var saturday = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(saturday.DayOfWeek, DayOfWeek.Saturday,
        "Test setup fail");
    var clock = new FakeSystemClock() { Now = saturday };
    var service = new Service(clock);

    // Act
    service.DoSomething();
}
```

In your application project you can define an `ISystemClock` implementation that actually uses the system clock. Using the given `ISystemClock` definition, it will look like this:

```
public class RealSystemClock : ISystemClock
{
    public DateTime Now => DateTime.Now;
}
```

When you use a DI container, you can configure it to wire up your types and automatically inject instances of `RealSystemClock` when a constructor specifies a `ISystemClock` argument.

btw. While you could use `Func<DateTime>` delegates to do the trick, defining an interface for this is IMO much more explicit, less ambiguous, and more readable to other developers. Besides that, wiring everything in a DI container would be easier, because it's easy to end up with multiple `Func<DateTime>` dependencies that all do different things than "give me the current local time".

Comment: Also consider these alternative names for `ISystemClock`: `ITimeProvider`, `IClock`. Also, when you follow the Framework Design Guidelines strickly, the `ISystemClock.Now` property should be a method, possibly be named `GetCurrentTime()` or `GetCurrentLocalTime()` (in fact, `DateTime.Now` should have been a method, not a property).

Answer (score -1):

[Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/) might be a solution/alternative for new projects as it all interface based and, thus, easily mock-able.