# How to replace time() function for testing production library?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, time, cross-platform

I want to write blackbox tests for my C library which uses standard C time functions (time(), localtime(), gmtime() etc) to use timestamps in its output. Output is encoded, so I need to replace those time functions with some testing mock or "backdoor" so I can control the value my library gets from time() function instead of current system time, so I can properly write checks in my tests.

What's the best approach to achieve this? Can I have such support in production library (with some knob maybe?), or should I compile my library in 2 forms: for production with real time() functions and for testing with my own controlled time() functions?

I'm interesting in cross-platform solution, so tricks like LD_PRELOAD is not a solution for me.

**Update**: I understand that I should provide some wrappers around real time() functions, and I will do those wrappers. My question is: can I have those in my production library and control in the runtime, or I never should do this and always should compile 2 libraries: one for production and second for testing?

Comment: love this question. I often read statements like 'mock this, mock that' where this and that are things like the filesystem, the network,.. but I don't think I've seen this done in code anywhere (didn't search thoroughly though).

Comment: See this SO question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594652/strategies-for-dealing-with-datetime-now-in-unit-tests/4594995#4594995

Comment: @stijn: I can replace calls to real time() functions to wrapper functions which either call real time() functions or my own fake time() functions, I just need to figure out how to control which kind of functions will be used in the runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The way I have done this in the past, for an embedded C project, was to create two projects/configurations.
One configuration was for the production environment, containing all of the production code (including the dependencies), and the other was for unit-testing and contained the testing driver and all the mocks. The two configurations shared the sources of the code to be tested.
In the unit-test environment, I just linked to mocks or fakes of all the external functions required by the code-under-test.

There are several ways you can link the code-under-test to the mocks that it requires:

- You just provide the object-file(s) with the mocks to the linker. Most linkers will first use the names they find in the specified object files, bore trying to resolve them with names from libraries. Some linkers honour the order in which object files and libraries are specified on the command line, so in those cases you should make sure the mocks are specified before the library (if you specify the library at all).
  For functions from the C standard library, this technically causes undefined behaviour, but in most cases it works out well even for those functions.
- You create a set of wrapper macros that you can switch around with a define. For example:

  ```
  #ifdef UNIT_TEST
    #define my_time time_mock
  #else
    #define my_time time
  #endif
  ```
- You create a set of wrapper functions (implemented in a different source file), and provide mocks of those functions. This has the slight disadvantage that those functions can't be unit-tested without using one of the techniques of the preceding bullets.

**Update:** Even if your production code goes into a library, the unit-test configuration should produce (one or more) executables.
Unit test code should not be included in the production library (although you may consider including it in a source distribution), because it adds only extra baggage with a potential for causing errors. Would you like it if one of your customers accidentally switches the library in unit-test mode and starts complaining that it is broken?

Comment: Couldn't you simplify the define as `#ifdef UNIT_TEST / #define time(x) time_mock(x) / #endif`?  Replaces all function calls without changing the names of variables or structure elements.

Comment: @tomlogic: Formally, it is undefined behaviour (`time` is reserved for the implementation if you have `#include <time.h>`), and it has a higher chance of actually failing (e.g. if `<time.h>` also declares `time()` as a macro) in addition to the fact you have to be more careful with the order of your #include-s.

Answer (score 1):

I would wrap the calls an check a static variable (unitTest). So you could initialze the behaviour anytime from your configuration file.

```
time_t myTime( time_t * timer ) 
{
    if ( unitTest ) {
        return TIME_TEST;
    }
    return time( timer );
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use global `unitTest` variable? and control its value from my testing environment to force TIME_TEST? Is it possible to avoid global variable?

Comment: @bialix you could declare it as static so that the scope is limited to your wrapper source file (translation unit) and provide methods to enable/disable the unittest behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

(I think you are not asking about the implementation details, but whether you should make it a compile-time, a deploy-time, or a runtime config aspect.)

I think it really depends.

If you have a well-know config mechanism (be it a config file, an environment variable, command-line parameters, whatever) for the field, I would add this as a config item there. Then you can use exactly the same binaries in production as in testing. Some organizations demand this very strictly.

Since you will never need that feature in production, I'd recommend to make this a compile-time config item so you can be 100% sure you will never mis-configure the app in production since would not support that feature. (Of course, you must make absolutely sure that you never deploy a binary compiled for testing to production.) Conditional defines/conditional compilation is a good choice here, I think.

That's all there is to say about it, no?

Comment: "Then you can use exactly the same binaries in production as in testing. Some organizations demand this very strictly." Those requirements are typically for system-level testing with external tests. I have never seen such a requirement for unit testing. Additionally, those organisations will typically also demand a proven test coverage of 80+% of the code in that binary, which means you have to create off-line tests for the testcases and mocks in that binary. I don't think execution of the testcases will be accepted as coverage for the testcases themselves.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau, sqlite does both. They test the binary for passing tests, and then test the code for code coverage.