# Why pass func<T> to constructor rather than T?

Tags: c#, linq, func

I came across the accepted answer of this question [about dealing with DateTime.Now in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594652/strategies-for-dealing-with-datetime-now-in-unit-tests) which contains the following code example:

```
private readonly Func<DateTime> _nowProvider;
public SomeClass(Func<DateTime> nowProvider)
{
    _nowProvider = nowProvider;
}

public bool Foo()
{
    return (_nowProvider().DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
}
```

Instantiated as such:

```
var s = new SomeClass(() => DateTime.Now);
```

I've not much used `Func<T>` in C# so I thought I'd take a look [at the Microsoft documentation for it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) which has the following remarks:

> You can use this delegate to represent a method that can be passed as a parameter without explicitly declaring a custom delegate. The encapsulated method must correspond to the method signature that is defined by this delegate. This means that the encapsulated method must have no parameters and must return a value.

Why would it be more beneficial in the example to pass a `Func<DateTime>`, instantiated as `Class(() => DateTime.Now)` to the constructor

Rather than to just simply pass in a `DateTime` parameter instantiated as `Class(DateTime.Now)` to the constructor?

According to the Microsoft documentation mentioned above LINQ lambda constructors also take `Func<T>` arguments and my experience with these proves they are extremely flexible but I can't understand why?

Comment: So the class can call it anytime to get an updated result. If you just passed T, the value would be fixed forever. It also make testing easier because you can easilly _cheat_ the value for the sake of testing

Comment: This could make sense for unit testing

Comment: It would allow unit tests to provide a specific time for testing time based functions.

Comment: The test wants something that can *provide it with the current time*, not *the current time*. Think of the function as a clock. It need not even be a real clock that runs at a fixed rate, which is of course very useful in a unit test that shouldn't be constrained to wall clock time.

Comment: Can you think of any other obvious scenarios outside of unit testing where passing the func<T> might be beneficial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Rather than to just simply pass in a DateTime parameter instantiated as Class(DateTime.Now) to the constructor?

Because the value should be the current DateTime and not the one when the class has been instanciated.

When the code runs, the Func returns the *Date of exactly when the code is executed*.

If the DateTime would be stored in a field, it would be the time of creation, not now.

---

I have an example.

Let's say you create an instance of `Class` at 23:59:55 on Saturday.

10 Seconds later, the following snipped:

```
(passedDateTime.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

would return false.

With the provider, the datetime is actually on sunday - the time it is executed at.

---

Technical:

DateTime is a struct.

When passing DateTime to a method or constructor as a parameter, it is passed as a value, not a reference.

Thus the `DateTime` will not be up to date, but just a snapshot of the value.

You can confirm this yourself:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.Now;

System.Threading.Sleep(1000);
bool equals = dateTime == DateTime.Now; // false
```

Answer (score 3):

This pattern allows the Date and Time to be provided either by `DateTime.Now`, during normal operation, or to be closely controlled during unit testing.

For example, a Unit Test that wants to test time based functionality could verify that the returned result is correct when a function is called twice with more than 5 minutes between each call (a common caching technique), without having to wait 5 minutes between calls.

---

It is also an example of the "Inversion of Control" pattern.  Where a method of retrieving  data is "injected" in to the class, usually via constructor.  The class is then free to use whatever method was injected without being aware of its implementation.

Comment: "The class is then free to use whatever method was injected without being aware of its implementation." Absolutely! Great point.

Comment: This can also be extremely useful during coded UI testing, or even interactive user testing, where you want to see how things behave at specific times of the day.  An option can be added to the UI to "force" the system to think that it is a specific time of day.

Answer (score 2):

I attach a small example on how this could look like in a unit test.

If you would not have the ability to provide a different "Now" the unit test will behave different depending on the time it runs.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFoo()
    {
        var obj = new SomeClass(() => DateTime.Now);

        //Only true on sundays
        Assert.IsTrue(obj.Foo());

        //This is sunday
        obj = new SomeClass(() => new DateTime(2017, 7, 30));
        //This will be always true
        Assert.IsTrue(obj.Foo());

        //This is not sunday
        obj = new SomeClass(() => new DateTime(2017, 7, 29));
        //This will be always false
        Assert.IsFalse(obj.Foo());
    }
```